# How to make a microservice backend with lambda communicate with each other?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, microservices, aws-api-gateway

I've an API Gateway with 2 lambdas behind it. lambda A is responsible for all `/orders` calls and the other one (lamda B) for all `products/`. So you can create an order by using lambda A but then the delete product function in products should be triggered. The amount of products should reduce. This functions is created in lambda B and can also be triggered from the API Gateway (but then by an admin instead of an end user).

Is this a normal way things get handled in microservices? Which way do AWS recommend? I read about publishing to SNS to trigger the other lambda but I don't see the solution immediately since they should be triggered by API Gateway too. I was also reading about step functions but this seems fine for more strict cases.